# How to read an online XML file for currency rates in java

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm building a simple currency converter which needs to sue online rates. I found the following API from the European Central Bank to use:
http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

My problem is im struggling to implement it. Here is what i have so far after using a bunch of different sources to try and get this code together.

```
        try{
                URL url = new URL("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");

                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nodeList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Cube");
                for(int i = 0; i < nodeList1.getLength(); i++){

                    Node node = nodeList1.item(i);

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
```

So what i thought is that this code would take down all the nodes which tart with "Cube", and contain the rates.

Anyone have an easier wya to pull down the rates from the API into an array in the order they appear on the XML as that's all I'm trying to do

Thanks

Comment: 1) What problems are you having with your current code? 2) have you looked into using XML libraries such as XPath or JAXB? 3) This is dangerous code: `catch(Exception e){  }`. Are you sure that you wish to ignore *all* exceptions?

Comment: myself, I'd just use XPath for this, checking all Cube nodes for attributes of "currency" and "rate". Easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XPath is one way to answer this, since you just want to extract information from the XML and not change the XML. The structure of the XML suggests that you're looking for nodes that are Cube nodes, that are child of Cube which is also a child of Cube -- Cube nested three times, so extract nodes with an XPath compiled using this String: `"//Cube/Cube/Cube"`.  This looks for nodes that have Cube nested 3 times located *anywhere* (the `//`) in the Document:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Cube/Cube/Cube");
```

Then check the nodes for a "currency" attribute. If they have this, then they also have a "rate" attribute, and then extract this information.

```
NamedNodeMap attribs = node.getAttributes();
if (attribs.getLength() > 0) {
    Node currencyAttrib = attribs.getNamedItem(CURRENCY);
    if (currencyAttrib != null) {
        String currencyTxt = currencyAttrib.getNodeValue();
        String rateTxt = attribs.getNamedItem(RATE).getNodeValue();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Where CURRENCY = "currency" and RATE = "rate"

For example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class TestXPath {
    private static final String CURRENCY = "currency";
    private static final String CUBE_NODE = "//Cube/Cube/Cube";
    private static final String RATE = "rate";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<CurrencyRate> currRateList = new ArrayList<>();
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        Document document = null;
        String spec = "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(spec);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            document = builder.parse(is);

            XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
            String xPathString = CUBE_NODE;
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xPathString);
            NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nl.item(i); 
                NamedNodeMap attribs = node.getAttributes();
                if (attribs.getLength() > 0) {
                    Node currencyAttrib = attribs.getNamedItem(CURRENCY);
                    if (currencyAttrib != null) {
                        String currencyTxt = currencyAttrib.getNodeValue();
                        String rateTxt = attribs.getNamedItem(RATE).getNodeValue();
                        currRateList.add(new CurrencyRate(currencyTxt, rateTxt));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SAXException | IOException | XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (CurrencyRate currencyRate : currRateList) {
            System.out.println(currencyRate);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class CurrencyRate {
    private String currency;
    private String rate; // ?double

    public CurrencyRate(String currency, String rate) {
        super();
        this.currency = currency;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    public String getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CurrencyRate [currency=" + currency + ", rate=" + rate + "]";
    }

    // equals, hashCode,....
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, im currently working on this but getting a ndroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException which is really bugging me. Ive tried to switch it to a class which extends AsyncTask but thats not really working :L

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels My bad. I thought I had done it, I really appreciated this answer, put me in the right direction